# Shared element fragment transition not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have two Fragments hosted in one Activity. They are dead simple:

```
class OneFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)

        val sharedView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.shared_view)
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(sharedView, "test")

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.go_button).setOnClickListener {
            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

            val oneFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_frame_layout)
            val twoFragment = TwoFragment()

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                val moveTransition = TransitionInflater.from(activity).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)

                oneFragment.exitTransition = Fade()

                val transitionSet = TransitionSet()
                transitionSet.addTransition(TransitionInflater.from(activity).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move))
                transitionSet.duration = 600
                twoFragment.sharedElementEnterTransition = transitionSet

                twoFragment.enterTransition = Fade()

                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(TwoFragment::class.java.simpleName)
                fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(sharedView, "test")
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_frame_layout, twoFragment)
                fragmentTransaction.commit()
            }
            else {
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(TwoFragment::class.java.simpleName)
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_frame_layout, twoFragment)
                fragmentTransaction.commit()
            }
        }

        return view
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kravtsov.transitiontest.MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shared_view"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/shared_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="HELLO"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="GO"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the second one:

```
class TwoFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false)

        val sharedView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.shared_view)
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(sharedView, "test")

        return view
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kravtsov.transitiontest.MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shared_view"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="WORLD"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see they have common shared view, that i want to animate during transition. The problem is - animation never appears. I can see that enter and exit fade transition for the rest of elements working correctly. Only shared element transition do not work.

I've searched web a lot and mimic a lot of guiedes... No answers i found still. Does anyone face such an issue? Where shoud i start to fix this bug?

Comment: Try to apply `transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true)`.

Comment: No effect for transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me. I've used your layout and kotlin code, and it works seamlessly. One thing I took care of is importing all classes of support packages.